# Why MSVC accepts to instanciate a template class without template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012

```
template< typename Type >
struct TEqualTo
{
    bool operator() (Type const& lhs, Type const& rhs ) const
    {
        return lhs == rhs;
    }
};
// .... later in a function that takes a functor:
Find(a, TEqualTo());
```

MSVC accepted it, then I commited, then I got build error reports from other compilers, based on gcc I suppose.

> missing template arguments before '(' token

obviously the fix was to use the `T` from the Find function (`T` is the type of `a`) and it becomes:

```
Find(a, TEqualTo<T>());
```

and all is well.
Now the question, how on earth was the first construct ever allowed by MSVC (2012) ?

I see only one reason, the only member of the class is the operator() function, therefore there is nothing really to instanciate, not even a typedef. So the compiler realised that it could deduce `Type` from later operator() instanciation. which is nice but weird no ? is this standard ?

Comment: Speaking of that, why *isn't* the template parameter on the function instead of the class? You've basically remade `std::equal_to`, which is better than this one as of C++14, where you can do `std::equal_to<>()`.

Comment: Are you really asking why a compiler has a bug in the implementation? I know of very little programmers that never makes mistakes, I guess the answer is that: *We are (mostly everyone) humans*.

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast: of course I have remade std::equal_to, this is the purpose. there just are some environments where you don't include stl headers :'( (licence reasons and other political reasons). However regardless of that, here I am totally beffudled by why did MSVC passed the build, like if it was able to retroactively deduce `Type` from the later function instanciation, which is crazy. powerful but... I don't know if standard. this is the question. Also you are right the template could be on the function.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I am not asking that yet. I also doubt this is a bug, this is kind of basic and MSVC2012 is a crazy powerful, standard compliant compiler, that works really well. So maybe this in particular, is somekind of Uberpower that is slightly off standard but helpful, that MS decided to include. I want to know that !

Comment: MS2012 is one toolset, and it has its good and its bad parts. Is it standards compliant? To some extent, but not truly. It is actually quite easy to build a correct program **with templates** that will produce the wrong result in VS (wrong according to the standard) Diverging from the standard is **not** a superpower but a curse for its users (vendor lock in)